# How to batch delete with query builder

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I have array of id's I want to delete all of them with one query without `foreach` and eloquent, is there any way of it?

```
     $data= array(
      array(
        "id"=> "8",
        "id"=> "9"
      );

DB::table('table_name')->delete($data);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [WhereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#where-clauses):

```php
$data = array(8, 9);

DB::table('table_name')->whereIn('id', $data)->delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
$data = array( 8, 9 );

DB::table('table_name')->whereIn( 'id', explode(",", $data) )->delete();
```

Comment: this way it is deleting only first record, record number 8 not both of them :(